# Reactor Core - Mono - onErrorFlatmap

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, project-reactor, reactor

Is there a way in `Mono` to return a `flatMap` while there is an error(`onErrorFlatMap`)

My scenario is, i would need the SubscriberContext when there is an error after processing i need the same error propagated down the chain

```
    String test = "test";
    Mono.just(test)
            .map(Integer::valueOf)
            .onErrorMap(error -> Mono.subscriberContext()
                    .map(context -> {
                        System.out.println(error + " --   " + context.getOrDefault("APPID", null));
                        return error;
                    }))
            .subscriberContext(of("APPID", "APP-101"))
            .block();
```

This is the way, i found to fix it, but is there a better way?

```
String test = "test";
Mono.just(test)
        .map(Integer::valueOf)
        .onErrorResume(error -> Mono.subscriberContext()
                .flatMap(context -> {
                    System.out.println(error + " --   " + context.getOrDefault("APPID", null));
                    return Mono.error(error);
                }))
        .subscriberContext(of("APPID", "APP-101"))
        .block();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `onErrorResume` and ultimately returning a `Mono.error` is the correct and recommended pattern for this use case.